# with the purpose to or with the purposes to?

Tags: word-choice

Shall I say with the `purposes` to or with the `purpose` to

```
   I am doing several comparisons with the purposes to :
  1-
  2-
  3-
```

As you can see I have three purposes so I am confused which one singular or plural is right?

Comment: I would either go with "... with the following purposes:" or "... with the purpose to achieve the following:"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither. Just say

> I am making several comparisons *to*:
>
> - 1- see the difference;
> - 2-
> - 3-

Or

> I am making several comparisons for the purpose *of*:
>
> - 1- seeing the difference;
> - 2-
> - 3-

Comment: is it correct to say better seeing.

Comment: @sacvf no. You could say "to better see" but that is probably needlessly formal and will sound pretentious. it depends on the context.

Comment: but it is true to say `for the purpose of better understanding ....`what do u think?

Comment: @sacvf it's true but cumbersome and ugly. As I said, I can't give you a clearer answer unless you explain the context but the whole "for the purpose of" is not needed.